# echarts-for-react call component on clicking a data point on chart

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using *echarts* with react using *echarts* for react. I want to call a component on clicking a point on the graph, how to achieve this, and also what is legends, I read the documentation but was unable to understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass an object as onEvents prop to ReactEcharts component.

```
<ReactEcharts ref={(e) => { this.echarts_react = e; }}
    onEvents= {this._onEvents}
/>
```

where _onEvents can be something like

```
_onEvents = {
  'click': this.onChartClick,
  'dataZoom': this.onDataZoom,
}
```

and

```
onChartClick = (params)=>{
    // Do what you want to do on click event. params depend on the  type of  chart 
}
```

Comment: this will only work with a functional component or if you bind your callback to your component class

Answer (score 9):

I found both answers a bit incomplete so here is mine.

I am using echarts v5.

**TLDR**: don't forget to bind your callback to your object if you use a class component

**Functional component**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactECharts from 'echarts-for-react';

function MyComp(props) {

  const options = { ... }

  const onChartClick = (params) => {
    console.log('Chart clicked', params);
  };

  const onEvents = {
    click: onChartClick,
  };

  return (
    <ReactECharts
      option={options}
      onEvents={onEvents}
    />
  );
}
```

**Class component**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactECharts from 'echarts-for-react';

class MyComp extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.options = { ... };
    this.onChartClick = this.onChartClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  onChartClick = (params) => {
    console.log('Chart clicked', params);
  };

  onEvents = {
    click: this.onChartClick
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <ReactECharts
        option={this.options}
        onEvents={this.onEvents}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

onEvents prop not working properly, try getting ref of echarts and add your event to zr object like below:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            graphOption: {
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'value'
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
                    type: 'line'
                }]
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.echartsInstance = this.echartsReactRef.getEchartsInstance();
        this.zr = this.echartsInstance.getZr();

        this.zr.on('click', this.onChartClick);
    }

    onChartClick = (...rest) => {
        console.log('App:onClickChart', rest);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">

                    <ReactEcharts
                        style={{height: '100vh', width: '100vw'}}
                        ref={(e) => {
                            this.echartsReactRef = e;
                        }}
                        option={this.state.graphOption}
                    />
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this will not get you the usual echart parameters in the callback

Answer (score 1):

As kursat says, the onEvents property doesn't work properly (in my case it re-renders the chart when clicking on other DOM elements). He proposes to use the getZr() function, but this function does not return the usual parameters of echart.
I used the echarts instance on() function instead of getZr().on():

```
const myEchart = () => {

    const options = {};
    const chartRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        let instance = chartRef.current.getEchartsInstance();
        instance.on('click', (params) => {
            console.log(params); // contains echarts usual params
        });
    }, []);

    return <ReactECharts ref={chartRef} option={options} />;
};
```